# importing from a text file to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

filename:`dictionary.txt`

```
YAHOO:YHOO
GOOGLE INC:GOOG
Harley-Davidson:HOG
Yamana Gold:AUY
Sotheby’s:BID
inBev:BUD
```

code:

```
infile = open('dictionary.txt', 'r')
content= infile.readlines()
infile.close()

counters ={}
for line in content:
        counters.append(content)
        print(counters)
```

i am trying to import contents of the file.txt to the dictionary. I have searched through stack overflow but please an answer in a simple way (not with open...)

Comment: when dealing with a file you should use `open()` function one way or another(anyhow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, instead of opening and closing the files explicitly you can use `with` statement for opening the files which, closes the file automatically at the end of the block.

Secondly, as the file objects are iterator-like objects (one shot iterable) you can loop over the lines and split them with `:` character. You can do all of these things as a [*generator expression*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) within `dict` function:

```
with open('dictionary.txt') as infile:
    my_dict = dict(line.strip().split(':') for line in infile)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't have semi-colons in your keys.
In that case you should:

```
#read lines from your file
lines = open('dictionary.txt').read().split('\n')
#create an empty dictionary
dict = {}
#split every lines at ':' and use the left element as a key for the right value
for l in lines:
    content = l.split(':')
    dict[content[0]] = content[1]
```